# How to Create push notofication from local server to Android Device - No GCM, No Internet Connection

Tags: android, push-notification, push

Is there a way to push data from local server or create push notification (hosted on intranet) to an Android application without internet connection? 
The app is supposed to work only on LAN over WIFI. GCM is out of picture as internet connection is not available.

However the app will be running on both the devices all the time.

The model, I am talking about, is something like this:

Devices: Local Server - Wifi Connection - Android Device 1, Android Device 2

Android Device 1 updates some data on local server over wifi... Server needs to notify Android Device 2 about the change over Wifi.

Thank You very much for the help

Comment: I dont think without `Internet` it's possible.

Comment: there will be local server..
and application is connected to that server...
i want to send notification from local server to android device..

Comment: That's fine but how you recognized your device?

Comment: device will get registered  in local server and will always connected through local server with the help of wifi..

Comment: try p2p wifi connection for this,it ll help you to implement this.

Comment: do you have any example or link for it that would help me to implement..

Comment: @Prag's but at the side of your local server you need to start some `CRON` that will send a `Notification` to all devices. But i dont know it's possible. BTW you're idea is great. I like it.

Comment: but its a need of client so i have to find any way to implement this....
if u have any idea about this...please share...

Answer (score 0):

establish a socket server and run a socket client thread in android. Broadcast on server side with some info and receive it on client side.

Comment: do you have any example for it..??

Comment: but that would not be push !! as it will involve continuous polling and blocking operation

Comment: @r4jiv007 The push technique also works over a persistent socket connection to some server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using eneter messaging framework which used Web Socket/ TCP-IP